# Execution of PHP insertion webservice using cron job in XAMPP localhost server

Tags: php, windows-7, cron, xampp

I want to execute a PHP insertion webservice at a particular time using a cron job in XAMPP localhost server and Windows 7 OS, can you tell me how to execute it in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Scheduler (type Sched into the search box and it'll appear)OR go to Start > Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Scheduled Tasks
2. Click 'Create Task'.
3. The Scheduled Task Wizard will appear. Give the task you wish to generate a name and a brief description if you so wish.
4. Click the 'Actions' tab then click 'New'. Leave the top option at its default, which is 'Start Program'.
5. In the 'Program/script' box click browse to your favourite browser and select its executable file (eg: firefox.exe)
6. In the 'Add arguments' box put the address of your cron.php file, eg: http://www.yourdomain.com/runcron.php
7. Go to the 'Triggers' tab and select any time once per day (or whatever frequency you prefer) then fine tune the conditions from within the 'Settings' tab. Done!

Hope this help! Details on **[here](http://www.paterico.com/windows-cron.html)**.

PS. you can aslo run on **localhost**

Comment: can u tell how to write cron.php file for a php insertion webservice

Comment: it's pretty simple. you can learn in here. http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json. if you have problem in webservice, please free to contact me.

Comment: can i execute normal php webservice for corn job?

Comment: Internet resource say, "yes you can". My point theory point of view is yes, you can.

Comment: k.. i excute it is worked successfully, can u tell me how to use corn job to excute the same webservice at a given time in the live server without using task scheduler

Comment: say honestly, I don't how to use without task scheduler in Windows. But, Linux platform can work without task scheduler.